# Ubuntu 17.10 on Razer Blade GeForce GTX 1060 logs out automatically every 5 seconds but only after I close and reopen the laptop lid

Tags: nvidia, logout

This is my very first post and I want to thank you all in advance.
I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Razer Blade GeForce GTX 1060. It works well as long as I do not close and reopen the computer lid. Ater, I log back in I get logged out automatically every 5 seconds. I then restart the machine and it works fine again.

So far I have tried the following (without any luck):
1. Reinstalling the OS
2. Using the NVIDIA proprietary drivers
3. NOT using NVIDIA proprietary drivers
4. Set the screen lock to off in the privacy settings
5. Ask my colleagues to review the logs (nothing strange was detected)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exact same problem about a month ago right after installing Linux Mint, I switched to Ubuntu 17.10, then 16.04 and then I realized it was a problem inherent to the Razer Blade: when closing the lid to suspend after booting up and re-openning it, the laptop just loops into sleep cycles.

To solve it:

Solution from the [Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade)  (<del>Not tested by me, yet</del> works great):

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Add `button.lid_init_state=open` to your GRUB options as follow: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"`
- Be sure to **update the grub** afterward: 
  Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot and pray

Alternative method from the Ubuntu forum (a bit more hacky):

- In /etc/systemd/logind.conf change `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`
- In `/etc/acpi/events/` create a file called `laptop-lid-close` and put this in it:

  ```
  event=button/lid
  action=/etc/acpi/lidclose.sh
  ```
- Then create another file in `/etc/acpi/` called `lidclose.sh` and put this in it:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
  ```

  Be sure that you can run `sudo pm-suspend` on your distro before attempting this. I know this **works very well on Ubuntu 16.04 but it may not work on 17.10**. 
  Also I noticed that when I close the lid the razer logo doesn't dim so I have to half open it and about a second after close it back and then the logo dims. But as long as the suspend problem is solved, it's okay for me :)
- Reboot before testing, just in case.

Sources:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184159
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1652574&p=10283728#post10283728
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade