# Ubuntu 19.04 logs out randomly after first sleep

Tags: 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my computer, and ever since I installed it, I've been getting this weird bug where, after the first sleep, if I try to log in again, Ubuntu will keep logging out. The only way I've been able to bypass this is by powering off my computer (by holding down the power button), and logging in again. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 17.10 on Razer Blade GeForce GTX 1060 logs out automatically every 5 seconds but only after I close and reopen the laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992383/ubuntu-17-10-on-razer-blade-geforce-gtx-1060-logs-out-automatically-every-5-seco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post help me fix my problem. It seems like it's a problem specific to Razer Blade: [Ubuntu 17.10 on Razer Blade GeForce GTX 1060 logs out automatically every 5 seconds but only after I close and reopen the laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992383/ubuntu-17-10-on-razer-blade-geforce-gtx-1060-logs-out-automatically-every-5-seco)